# Android (OS6) runtime permissions callback thread for "onRequestPermissionsResult"

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

The Android OS 6 runtime permission model requires implementation of the callback method "onRequestPermissionsResult(....)" in the activity.

1) does the OS always initiate this callback on the UI thread?

2) Is it possible to programmatically select the thread on which the callback will occur (e.g. some dynamically generated background thread) ?

Can anyone shed some light on this?
Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the OS always initiate this callback on the UI thread?

Yes.

> Is it possible to programmatically select the thread on which the callback will occur (e.g. some dynamically generated background thread) ?'

No, though you are welcome to do something in `onRequestPermissionResult()` to affect a background thread (e.g., event bus event, post a job on executor's work queue).

Comment: Thnx for the quick response. I also was thinking that the callback happens on the UI thread, however I came across this library that suggests that user can choose the thread used by the callback:  

https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter  -

in the section titled "Handling listener threads"

Comment: @OkeUwechue: That is being handled somewhere inside the library.

Answer (score 0):

This must be done on the UI thread, which is one of course. Background threads can be multiple and they're used for tasks that don't block the UI. 
The purpose of runtime permissions is exactly that. To block the UI and wait user's action.

Comment: Thnx for the quick reply. Pls. also see above comment to @CommonsWare